# Tracepoint functionality while debugging C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio IDE, there seems to be an ability to use *tracepoints* as opposed to breakpoints while debugging. This allows one to debug code without having too many `printfs` clutter the code. An example of this feature on Visual Studio IDE is provided in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uld-2m2tGiI) video (time stamp [11 Mins, 14 Seconds](https://youtu.be/Uld-2m2tGiI?t=674)). Essentially, instead of writing inside of the code itself `printfs` to the screen or else `fprintfs` to a file that then has to be examined later on, when a breakpoint is hit, can some logging information be printed/logged out visually into a debug console/output window?

Is a similar functionality available in VSCode for C++ specifically? At present, when I edit a breakpoint in VSCode, it only allows setting of a conditional breakpoint. The video does not talk about debugging C++ code but is focused on C# and the presenter does state that many of the features overlap with C++.

At present, I compile and build my code for debugging via the following task:

```
    {
            "label": "winbuilddebug",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "msbuild",
            "args": [
                ".vscode/windows.vcxproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/property:Configuration=Debug",
                "/property:Platform=x64",
                "/t:build",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "base": "$msCompile",
                "fileLocation": "absolute"
            }
    }
```

Then, I set up breakpoints and then hit `F5` to start debugging. I do not use any other extension specifically for debugging/running, etc.

Comment: in VSC it is called `Logpoint`: **Run** > **New Breakpoint** > **Logpoint**

Comment: Great! Thanks. Let me see if it works for C++

Comment: @rioV8 Could you indicate where these logs will be displayed? I am looking at the "Output" window at the bottom and choosing "Log (Window)", "Log (Main)", etc, but none of them seem to display this.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-extension-july-2020-update-doxygen-comments-and-logpoints/ seems to suggest that it does not work with MSBuild. I should possibly switch to GDB for this to work.

Comment: Interestingly, came across a very similar discussion here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2591 If that issue is not yet resolved, then I suppose logpoint debugging is not possible for C++ yet :-(

Comment: according to the issue it works with gcc/gdb, and have you tried the extension [Scriptpoints](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaxAbernethy2.scriptpoints)

Comment: I tried that on Windows. It did not seem to work. Possibly I am entering the syntax for the log wrong. I tried entering `log("Test message")` and `!log("Test message")` into the logpoint input space following the extension website neither seemed to produce anything. I will try on a gdb debugger later today and update

Comment: @rioV8 Logpoints work out of the box on gdb. No need of any extensions. the only downside I observe is that the evaluated expression is displayed in the Debug Console. The Debug console with gdb prints bunch of gdb internal stuff such as breakpoint hit, etc., that is really lengthy. Is there a way to scroll up and down the debug console using keybindings that you are aware of?

Comment: if you prefix your Logpoints with a known string you can filter the content of the Debug console (top right)

Comment: That is a neat trick!